# Is it possible to use a macro in function prototypes and definitions?

Tags: c, function, macros, prototype

I have a few functions sharing common arguments I want to pass across, so is it possible to use a macro to save me from repeatedly writing out the common arguments?

As an example, would the following work?

```
#define STD_ARGS arg1, int arg2, int arg3

foo(int STD_ARGS, int foo_arg1, int foo_arg2);
foo(int STD_ARGS, int foo_arg1, int foo_arg2) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Better absorb the `int` into your `STD_ARGS`, lest somebody later mistakes `STD_ARGS` for a weird way of naming _one_ argument. That if you absolutely must do this. Copy & paste can't be _that_ expensive in your editor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's legal.  Expansion of `#define`-d macros is nothing but a replacement of tokens, ignoring what (if anything) those tokens mean.

(Whether this is a good idea or not depends on how well it's documented, how far the usage spreads, and things like that.)

Comment: If I have the function prototypes are a seperate header file, does the `#define` have to be present in the header file? Since the header file is shared with other C files, ideally I'd like to keep the define as local as possible.

Comment: Yes, if the macro is used in a header file, it should be defined in that header file.  You could then `#undef` it later in the same header to prevent users of the header from accidentally abusing it.

Comment: So I'd have to `#define` the same macro twice (once in the header file [then cancelled with `#undef`] and once more in the source file)? I fear this may lead to inconsistent code if I change the macro definition in the source but forget to change in the header vice/versa.

Comment: @MiloChen, that is a large chunk of the reason we are saying that this is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works.
The work of macro is just it replaces the `STD_ARGS` with `arg1, int arg2, int arg3`.
before compliation. So, it is legal.